# When viewing a PDF in IE with Adobe Reader X, how to zoom to specific percentage?

Tags: internet-explorer, printing, adobe-reader

I have a PDF that can only be viewed in IE with Adobe Reader due to the DRM.

Printing is allowed, but as per the instructions, I need to zoom to a specific percentage to properly print the document (using the Current View option in the Print dialog).

When the PDF is read in the browser there is no menu bar and I only know how to zoom using the +/- buttons.

How can I zoom to a specific percentage?

Comment: Does a floating bar appear near the bottom (Read Mode)? Perhaps `Ctrl+H` (toggle Read Mode) will work.

Comment: @Bob `Ctrl+H` does the trick! Yes, the floating bar was always there, but it only has a +/- for zooming.

Comment: That *is* odd. Perhaps something this PDF defines.

Comment: I mean, it has the standard bar, but the only zoom controls are the +/-. I was unaware that the Adobe Reader icon toggles Read Mode.

Comment: Honestly, I just stumbled across it one day (it was actually a misclick, and before I knew it was called Read Mode). In the standalone Reader program, it uses a cross within a circle instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have [Read Mode](http://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/2011/11/turning-off-read-mode-while-viewing-pdfs-in-your-browser/) enabled. It can be toggled with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>.

In Read Mode you actually get a floating bar near the bottom centre of your screen. You can also click the Reader symbol in the circle to switch back to normal mode:

[[image: Image from Adobe]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdjSq.png)

Aside from PDF defined Read Mode settings, standalone PDFs open in normal view while PDFs opened within a browser open in Read Mode. To open in normal view by default within a browser (aside from PDFs created to always open in Read Mode), in the preferences (`Edit` > `Preferences` in the Adobe Reader program):

[[image: Image from Adobe]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhUNG.jpg)